# Putting/Updating item in DynamoDB fails for the UpdateExpression syntax

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

I've created a DynamoDB table, and in my Python code, I have the resource initialised as follows:

```
self.dynamodb = self.session.resource('dynamodb').Table('aws-ci')
```

The table has just one index/key, with the name `environment`. I am trying to `PUT` into it, an object as follows:

```
{
  "environment": "beta",
  "X": {
    "current_sha": "sha1",
    "deployed": true,
    "prev_sha": "sha2",
    "status": "inactive"
  },
  "Y-Z": {
    "current_sha": "sha1",
    "deployed": false,
    "prev_sha": "sha2",
    "status": "active"
  }
}
```

where, `X` and `Y-Z` are the names of micro-services. My insertion code is as follows:

```
def put_service_data(self, environment, service_name, service_data, status = None):
    get_previous = self.dynamodb.get_item(
        Key = {
            'environment': environment
        }
    ).get(service_name)
    service_data['prev'] = get_previous and get_previous.get('current_sha') or 'NULL'
    if status == 'rollback' and get_previous:
        service_data['current'] = get_previous.get('current_sha')
        service_data['prev'] = get_previous.get('prev_sha')
    set_query = "SET {0}.current_sha = :current, {0}.prev_sha = :prev, {0}.deployed = :is_deployed, {0}.current_status = :status".format(service_name)
    updated = self.dynamodb.update_item(
        Key = {
            'environment': environment
        },
        UpdateExpression = set_query,
        ExpressionAttributeValues = {
            ':current': service_data.get('current'),
            ':prev': service_data.get('prev'),
            ':status': service_data.get('status'),
            ':is_deployed': service_data.get('deployed')
        },
        ReturnValues = "ALL_NEW"
    )
    return updated
```

Previously, instead of `{0}.current_status`, I had `{0}.status`, but that raised the following error:

> An error occurred (`ValidationException`) when calling the
>   `UpdateItem` operation: Invalid `UpdateExpression`: Attribute name is
>   a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: `status`

Anyway, I changed that attribute name name to `current_status` and tried the insertion again, only this time I am receiving:

> An error occurred (`ValidationException`) when calling the
>   `UpdateItem` operation: The document path provided in the update
>   expression is invalid for update

when trying to set attributes for service **X**, and the following when trying for **Y-Z**:

> An error occurred (`ValidationException`) when calling the
>   `UpdateItem` operation: Invalid `UpdateExpression`: Syntax error;
>   token: "-", near: "Y-Z"

I'm currently unable to understand how the `update_item` call should work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried this?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html#ExpressionAttributeNames

```
set_query = "SET #service_name.current_sha = :current, #service_name.prev_sha = :prev, #service_name.deployed = :is_deployed, #service_name.current_status = :current_status"
updated = self.dynamodb.update_item(
    Key = {
        'environment': environment
    },
    UpdateExpression = set_query,
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ':current': service_data.get('current'),
        ':prev': service_data.get('prev'),
        ':current_status': service_data.get('status'),
        ':is_deployed': service_data.get('deployed')
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames = {
         '#service_name': service_name,
    },
    ReturnValues = "ALL_NEW"
)
```

Comment: Yeah, that was all. :/ I don't know how I missed that parameter in the docs.

Comment: Would it work if I change `current_status` back to `status`?

Comment: If you do that, then you need to add status to the ExpressionAttributeNames